# Cannot find a suitable pyspark Docker image for Python 3.7

Tags: python, docker, pyspark

I am looking for a Docker image to test some `pyspark` code in Circle CI. Our ETL currently uses `python 3.7` and `pyspark` version 3.1.2.

I have been trying to find a Docker image with Spark and from Python 3.7 to no avail.

When I look on docker hub [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/pyspark-notebook/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated&name=python-3) I also don't find an image.

Answer (score -1):

You can easy build your own Docker with `python 3.7` and `pyspark` version 3.1.2

1. Create Dockerfile

```
#cat Dockerfile                                   
FROM python:3.7

RUN pip3 install pyspark==3.1.2
```

2. Then build an image( replace with your own creds):

```
docker build  -t krasnosvar/pyspark:3.1.2 .
```

Comment: I was hoping to find a pre-built image, as I also need to ensure the `java` dependencies etc are all set up appropriately.